# What is the syntax for GotoIf with & condition in asterisk server?

Tags: asterisk

```
exten => s,n,GotoIf($["${choice}" = "*"] & $["${isharvesttoday}" = "1"]?question4)
```

The above line is not worked in my application. Is this syntax is correct?

Comment: @jordon: I tried to your updated line, still it is not working correctly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it isn't. This should work:

```
exten => s,n,GotoIf($[$["${choice}" = "*"] & $["${isharvesttoday}" = "1"]]?question4)
```